# How to include an executable with my project and call it in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have an .exe file, which is just a command line tool for a certain encryption. I have a .NET project and I want to include this with my program and be able to make command line calls to this exe and gets its response...

How can I include this .exe?

Comment: You can make a class library that calls the executable.

Comment: @GianAcuna Sorry i'm fairly new to .NET, how do i make a class library?

Comment: is the commandline application console type or a winform ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be quite easily achieved using the [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) property. A full sample is contained in the linked MSDN documentation; the only caveat is that you may have to redirect the standard error stream as well to see all output of your application.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "your_application.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "argument1 argument2 argument2 ...";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();    

Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: thanks but how can I package this .exe with my program so when someone installs it, it's stored maybe with my .exe so they don't have to seperately install this .exe

Comment: u can use the .net setup & deployment, it asks for all the needed files, or there are many free Installer Creator use any one of them!

Comment: another option would be to insert the exe in the Resource of application & extract the exe if file not found!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class library (DLL) that calls the executable's functions. Basically, you reference the created DLL in your other project. It acts as a middle man between your application and the other executable.

See [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s16p1.html)

Include the executable project in your class library project so you can call the encryption function.

Comment: I include the .exe in my class library project? How will the DLL bring the .exe into my project. I want to make sure that people don't have to find and download the .exe.. I want to package it with my program

Comment: The .exe must be within the same directory as the DLL. You don't want the .exe in the install directory of your application? Hmm, for that I guess you'll have to include the source code of your .exe within your application. Do you have control over the .exe's project?

Comment: no i don't have control. I don't mind having the .exe in the install directory.. I guess i can just package that later when i'm creating the installer?

Comment: yes. but you'll need to have the project imported in your applications project so you can call its functions.